# ASP.NET Identity facebook login on amazon ec2 server 404 file or directory not found

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication, identity

I have developed a C# asp.net web forms application which uses ASP.net Identity to allow users register and login with their Facebook account.

The issue is this

- The login process works perfectly in IIS express when debugging in
  Visual Studio 2013
- The login process works perfectly when deployed to a test Win 2008 Server
  running in a VM on my development box

When I deploy to a Win 2008 Server instance running in Amazon EC2 I get a 404 - File or directory not found server error for the URL
http://www.thedomain.com/signin-facebook?code=AQCQmWqP7.......

The facebook OAuth Settings have had the redirect URL www.thedomain.com added

Absolutely no errors logged that might provide a clue as to what is happening and Fiddler has not provided any helpful information either.

Would really appreciate your thoughts and comments if you have encountered similar.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - at last

Turned out not to be related to the AWS platform and in truth I am not quite sure why it worked locally and not in production.

In any case

www.yourdomain.com/signin-facebook is the default CallBackPath in the FacebookAuthenticationOptions Properties

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{ 
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "111111",
            AppSecret = "dfadfafafaf",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/Default")
        });
}
```

Setting a value for the **CallBackPath property** in the Start.Auth.cs file resolved the issue.